# How do I get my asyncio client to call a socket server and waiting for response

Tags: sockets, client-server, synchronous, coroutine, python-asyncio

I am working with an `asyncio.Protocol` server where the purpose is for the client to call the server, but **wait** until the server has responded and data is returned before stopping the client loop.

Based on the asyncio doc Echo Client and Server here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocol-example-tcp-echo-server-and-client , results of transport.write(...) are returned immediately when called.

Through experience, calling `loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)` fails with `RuntimeError: Event loop is running.`

Running `asyncio.sleep(n)` in the `data_received()` method of the server doesn't have any effect either.

`yield from asyncio.sleep(n)` and `yield from asyncio.async(asyncio.sleep(n))` in `data_received()` both hang the server.

My question is, how do I get my client to wait for the server to write a response before giving back control?

Comment: Do you want to close client just after getting answer from server? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah, I want the functionality between client and server to act just like a typical synchronous method call, albeit a non-blocking one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess to never use transport/protocol pair directly.

asyncio has Streams API for high-level programming.

Client code can look like:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def communicate():
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(HOST, PORT)
    writer.write(b'data')
    yield from writer.drain()
    answer = yield from reader.read()
    # process answer, maybe send new data back to server and wait for answer again
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to change the client code.

**echo-client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import asyncio

class EchoClient(asyncio.Protocol):
    message = 'Client Echo'

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('data sent: {}'.format(self.message))

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('data received: {}'.format(data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('server closed the connection')
        asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_connection(EchoClient, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

The trick is to place your code (including self.transport methods) into a coroutine and use the `wait_for()` method, with the `yield from` statement in front of the statements that require their values returned, or ones which take a while to complete:

**echo-server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import asyncio

class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('data received: {}'.format(data.decode()))
        fut = asyncio.async(self.sleeper())
        result = asyncio.wait_for(fut, 60)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def sleeper(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
        self.transport.write("Hello World".encode())
        self.transport.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServer, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
print('serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exit")
finally:
    server.close()
    loop.close()
```

Call `echo-server.py` and then `echo-client.py`, the client will wait 2 seconds as determined by `asyncio.sleep`, then stop.

Comment: here `fut = asyncio.async(self.sleeper())`  async is giving syntax error.